# How to position a background image like wanderfly.com?

Tags: html, css, image, background

Hey guys. i want to be able to position my image background similar to
[www.wanderfly.com](http://www.wanderfly.com)  . the source of that page shows that they use an hidden input field:

```
<input value="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/32/35826109_27e678ec45_b.jpg" id="backgroundImage" type="hidden"></input>
```

I tried to look for the CSS implementation of "backgroundImage" but couldn't find it.
the image they use however is 1024:685 but they figured how to stretch it for higher resolution, giving that neat fullscreen display.

How would i be able to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add an `img` in your html with `id="background"`. In your css write this: `#background { width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XW9Pz/1/

Comment: don't forget the z-index:-9999 or your image won't behave much like a background image

Comment: it's only when i add height:100% that the image is in place. should i use the height also?

Comment: @Tom the above is just an example. If `height:100%` do what you want, use it.

Answer (score 0):

They have an absolutely positioned **foreground** image.

```
<div id="backstretch" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: fixed; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; z-index: -9999; ">
    <img style="position: relative; width: 969px; height: 643.4765625px; left: 0px; top: -63.23828125px; " src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2146/2428825658_c5f07a8f89_b.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: David, when i use this code in a plain html it just shows up regularly, not stretched

Comment: They use JavaScript to resize it on the fly — but I wouldn't suggest using it. Foreground images are content, not backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a fullscreen background image that stretches 100% width and height of a monitor without having it be squished or pinched because the users monitor is a widescreen, try the following code. it worked wonders for me.

**CSS:**

```
img.bg {
    /* Set rules to fill background */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;

    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    /* Set up positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0 ;
    z-index: -1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    img.bg {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -512px; 
    }
}
```

**HTML PAGE:**

```
<asp:Image ID="imgBG" runat="server" CssClass="bg" ImageUrl="~/Sites/0/PageLayouts/Images/Background.jpg" />
```

Comment: Also, for other elements overtop of the background image, you may have to add a z-index, but i did add -1 for this.