# I applied CSS auto-resizing to image, now how do I push it to the background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, background-image

Complete CSS newbie here who just applied the image resizing trick in the accepted answer to this question: [How to position a background image like wanderfly.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222618/how-to-position-a-background-image-like-wanderfly-com).

**Problem**: The resizing works great, but the image appears in the foreground, blocking the content in all of my pages rendered via yield.  How do I push the image to the background?

relevant portion of application.html.erb:

```
<body>
  <%= image_tag("background.jpg", :id => "background") %>
  <%= yield %>
</body
```

css stylesheet:

```
#background {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the comments to the answer you linked to:

> don't forget the z-index:-9999 or your
>   image won't behave much like a
>   background image

So:

```
#background {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -9999;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/XW9Pz/2/

Comment: geez, and I saw that comment too, it just didn't register because I didn't know what "z-index" was, but now it makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Read this to learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index